# Did Objective C start using + instead of | for combining bits?

Tags: objective-c

Anytime you combine two flags or more, you use |. Except Swift, which changed it to use array syntax. But now I am staring at some documentation on local notifications that does this:

```
requestAuthorizationWithOptions: (UNAuthorizationOptionAlert + UNAuthorizationOptionSound)
```

Where those are enums. I can't find where the + operator suddenly started working in this manner. I don't see any indicators that | couldn't just be used instead. I realize that maybe the enums themselves could just happen to work by the nature of their bits and how they add, but I doubt my last statement.

Comment: In the sense that they're "just bitpatterns" (and given that the flags themselves are bitmasks), why wouldn't plus do what you expect here?  It is definitely unorthodox, though.

Comment: If they're unique bitflags addition is equal to oring them. But only in that situation.

Comment: @CodaFi To be clear, adding the bit masks only works if none of the values have any common bits set. Using addition is a bad idea because it's risky and only works under very specific conditions that might change.

Comment: Right,  took the example from Apple's docs. Then a tutorial online has 3 enums all "added". Of which I found another one here: https://salesforce-marketingcloud.github.io/JB4A-SDK-iOS/features/iOS10-notifications.html 
It seems my last sentence in the question really was it... and yeah, rare times when the math works, agree with that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, to codify the discussion in comments above: no, `+` is not a replacement for `|`. `a + b == a | b` if and only if `a` and `b` have bitpatterns which share no overlapping bits; in the cases of option `enum`s, this is often true (because it is useful to represent options in this way), but not guaranteed. This is the case that you see above, though good code will be a bit more explicit (and readable) by using bitwise or.

Comment: Another case for avoiding `+` is that the actual value of the options such as `UNAuthorizationOptionAlert` are unknown so you can't safely assume that `+` will always work. It might work in one version of iOS and then break in a later version.

Comment: Yeah. Apple keeps rewriting the laws of everything so I wasn't sure if Apple just did that for Obj C after so much of swift doing same, or if the document, and subsequently tutorial writers, just used + out of laziness, stupidity, or worse, they actually know the math and threw it in there because they wanted to be uberl337... I hate uber-leet style code, those one-liners that confuse or use tons of dependencies slowing stuff down. Thanks for answering!